# JAVA - Most efficient way to remove file extension

Tags: java, file-extension

I want remove the extension of a file. For example:

- `ActualFile = image.png`
- `ExpectedFile = image`

Which method is the most efficient to use?

1. `removeExtension()` method provided by org.apache.commons.io
2. `fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'))`

Answer (score 5):

No difference, except one. Do you really want to add whole Apache lib to use only one method? If you use Apache in your application - then use it as well. If not - do create your custom implementation - this is not a rocket-science.

Comment: Agree with your concerns, also because the extension is just a suffix in the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [`removeExtension`](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.java#L1112) from `commons-io` you can see that `substring` is also used underwater in that method in a similar way you describe:

```
public static String removeExtension(final String fileName) {
    if (fileName == null) {
        return null;
    }
    failIfNullBytePresent(fileName);

    final int index = indexOfExtension(fileName);
    if (index == NOT_FOUND) {
        return fileName;
    }
    return fileName.substring(0, index);
}
```

Your method is faster since there are less operations being done, but the `removeExtension` method has the `failIfNullBytePresent` which states:

> Check the input for null bytes, a sign of unsanitized data being
>   passed to to file level functions.
>
> This may be used for poison byte attacks.

and `indexOfExtension` to get the index of the extension which has more checks (as you can see in the javadoc of that method [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.java#L734)).

### Conclusion

Your method is faster but I'd say using the `commons-io` is safer/more consistent in various situations, but what to use depends on how complex your situation is whether it's a critical feature of an application or just a home made project for yourself. `removeExtension` is not *that* complex or slow that you shouldn't use it perse.